# How to safely change PHP session.save_path permissions to allow built in server work

Tags: php, linux, session, yii2, file-permissions

I have installed [yii2](/questions/tagged/yii2) and I have tried to run using the PHP built in server using `./yii serve`. When I open `http://localhost:8080` I got the following permission error:

> PHP Warning – yii\base\ErrorException session_start():
>   open(/var/lib/php/sessions/sess_t1462ivbhhq79igqjp6b4fekth, O_RDWR)
>   failed: Permission denied (13)

On other application on the same machine that it run on Apache, I fired up `phpinfo()` and I found that path `/var/lib/php/sessions` is set to `session.save_path`.

To work around the permission issue, I have tried to run `sudo ./yii serve` and it worked fine.

Now, I care about the security of my development system, where, occasionally, I expose it to the Internet to serve my clients visits to the currently developed apps. I don't know weather I keep running the app using `sudo` or is there a better way to change `/var/lib/php/sessions` permissions to allow php from the cli, `php -S`, to access it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done the following to change the save session path to another accessible path by PHP cli:

1. From the terminal `php --ini` to get a list of configurations files and I meant by **Loaded Configuration File** entry to specify the path of the loaded `php.ini` file. In my case it is `/etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini`.
2. Using any text editor that could be run as sudo, in my case I used *kate*, I opened the specified `php.ini` file and I search for: `session.save_path` entry of the php.ini and I uncommented it then change the path to a path in my home. In my case I set it to be `/home/myuser/tmp/sessions`. Save the file.

Now `./yii serve` works fine without need to sudo and without need to change any settings of the php.ini for Apache.

Comment: Terminal and webserver may use different php.ini files, which is something one should be aware of (i.e. php --ini from a terminal may show a different configuration than that used by the webserver)